# How to cycle the kill ring in ipython5?

Tags: ipython, prompt-toolkit

IPython 5 has a bunch of neat new editing features, but it seems like cycling the kill ring is MIA.

Cycling the kill ring is done in IPython 4 (and any other readline-based program) by issuing a <kbd>Alt-y</kbd> following a yank (<kbd>Ctrl-y</kbd>).

Is this functionality not present in IPython 5, or am I just missing it?

---

Here's a full example, for anyone not familiar:

Push the word "one" onto the kill ring:

<kbd>o</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-k</kbd>

Push the word "two" onto the kill ring:

<kbd>t</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-k</kbd>

After a yank (<kbd>Ctrl-y</kbd>, which will insert "two"), you can start cycling the kill ring with <kbd>Alt-y</kbd>, to get the "one" back, for example.

Comment: This has been driving me crazy the last few weeks. I finally did some research and it seems that, as of now, [python-prompt-toolkit](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit) which IPython is now using doesn't yet have a `kill-ring` and thus `M-y` is not yet implemented (see [this comment](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9425#issuecomment-215948436) on IPython issues).

Comment: I just posted [an issue on python-prompt-toolkit](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit/issues/414)... maybe if I find a few extra minutes I'll try to dig in and figure out what it would take to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ever-luminous @jonathanslenders (maintainer of the python-prompt-toolkit library, which is where this problem lied) has [fixed the issue](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit/issues/414).